# Does "The OAuth client was deleted" from Google mean the keys are invalid?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, credentials, google-oauth

I am trying to track down leaked values for `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` and `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID`. I run this basic flask app [here](https://gist.github.com/saptarshiguha/480a7e77e28c6cebe1b6536af22a109b) in docker, link it to localhost, edit /etc/hosts to map that to "myserver.local.com" and access the page. When I click Login on the "This app will attempt to authenticate you through Google OAuth 2.0" screen, I get this error

```
Authorization Error
Error 401: deleted_client
The OAuth client was deleted
```

Excluding the possibility of restoring the project within 30 days of deletion, can I take this to mean that the leaked keys do not pose a threat? I cannot find them in our projects, so I cannot just delete them myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client ID contains the [project number](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#projects). The client ID is constructed the following way:

```
<PROJECT_NUMBER>-<RANDOM_STUFF>.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

If you have access to the project, you can access the list of credentials by going to the link `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<PROJECT_NUMBER>`.

In there, you can verify if the client ID has been deleted, and if not, delete it yourself.

You can also check if the project is pending deletion by using the same project number in this command (requires `gcloud` installed and properly authenticated):

```
curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H'Accept: application/json' \
'https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?filter=projectNumber%3A<PROJECT_NUMBER>'
```

As per the [API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects) definition, if the response has the field `"lifecycleState":"DELETE_REQUESTED"`, it means that the project is pending deletion but still recoverable.

All of these steps are contingent to you having access to the project with the credentials. If you don't have that access, you should find somebody who has. If that project was within an organization, someone with permissions at the organization level should have access to all the projects within.

With all that said, the error does look like it means the client was deleted, and there is no way to recover deleted credentials, at least according to the warning message when deleting one:

[image: Deleting credentials in GCP]

The biggest danger I see is that the leaked credentials contain the project number, but abusing only a project number is pretty hard.

Comment: It is very useful knowledge to have that the client ID contains the project number!

Comment: Note that this is an undocumented behaviour (as far as I know). It was added a few years ago, but you might still be able to find old client IDs without this format (e.g. the default client ID in the [oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), which can be seen in the URL when authorizing scopes), and Google can change this behaviour at any point in time. Nevertheless, I can guess that Google sees the value in keeping the project number in the client ID precisely for situations like this one.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your access token is revoked you can perform any of the following actions:

[Tokens: delete](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/delete) --> Delete all access tokens issued by a user for an application.

[gcloud auth revoke](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/revoke) --> Revokes the user account token on the server:

[Programatically revoke access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke)

[Change password](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6328616?hl=en)

You can also track your token with the [OAuth Token audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6124308?hl=en) to see when and by who it was used.

Comment: I think these might be for different tokens. I did not create this token, and I do not know which account or project it's in, so I don't think I can do the first method. The other three methods are not for the `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` and `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` values.